# How to do kevali pranayama or ajapa japa according to gheranda samhita?

Tags: mantras, yoga, pranayama, hatha-yoga

I've read gheranda samhita but I'm little confused how to do kevali pranayama or ajapa japa are both same? What is the exact process of doing it